# Regarding to use deployjava.js file

Tags: java, applet, deployjava

if any problem to use deployjava.js in my applictaion.
Is it open Source

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do/ask?

Comment: Better you google it out.

Comment: if any objection  to use this js file code or modified code

Comment: I downvoted because this question can be a whole lot better than it currently is. You should detail if you are going to make modifications to the file and if your application is commercial or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use it . These are the only restrictions.

https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.txt

```
 Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of Oracle nor the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
```